# How to fill the basis of vector subspace up to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, if we're given a vector subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with basis:
$$B_V=\{(-1,1,1),(2,1,-1)\}$$
How can we find a basis of vector subspace $F$ such that:
$$V\oplus F=\mathbb{R}^3 \ ?$$
What I did is just find a linearly independent vector of those two in $B_V$, for example, vector $(4,-1,-3)$, but, how can I be sure that it is the basis of $F$ and that:
$$V\cap F=\{0\}$$

Comment: The vectors in $F$ are just the scalar multiples of your $(4,-1,-3)$. Suppose that as in $B_V$, then you would have a linear dependence relation between the three vectors. Contradiction. Clearly the three vectors together give a space dimension 3. Take any other vector if it was linearly dependent we would have that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ exceeded 3!

Comment: So, their linear independence is a sufficient condition that their sum is a direct sum?